# gazebo8 depends on libignition-math2 and libignition-math3, which conflict

Tags: gazebo-8, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have installed gazebo 8 from the debs on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm getting an error that libignition-math2.so.2 is not found. When I try to install libignition-math2, apt tries to uninstall gazebo8 and the libignition-math3 libraries. I did try to install gazebo and ignition from source at one point, but I have already `sudo make uninstall`'ed those attempts. That stuff shouldn't affect what libraries the binary gazebo8 is trying to load though, right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15384/gazebo8-depends-on-libignition-math2-and-libignition-math3,-which-conflict/) by [ckchow](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3043/ckchow/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The latest package should depend only on ignition-math3. Could you try uninstalling Gazebo and all dependencies which depend on ign-math, updating your database and installing again? Something like this:

```
sudo apt remove '.*gazebo.*' '.*sdformat.*' '.*ignition-.*'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gazebo8
```

Let us know if the issue doesn't solve itself. Sorry for the trouble.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ckchow](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3043/ckchow/) on 2017-02-07**:
My specific problem (I think) was that there was a bunch of gazebo objects left in /usr/lib and other places from a bad source install. After I removed them, things worked again. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though!